# Creating a upload form with WordPress.com

Tags: wordpress

I have created a website with https://wordpress.com ,
I want to add a **file upload** button so that people could upload the files and as soon as they upload the file I want it to be uploaded on my site as well, and they must enter the authentication password before uploading. I am using the free plan of WordPress and hence can't install plugins.
In case more information needed please feel free to ask.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without plugins... at least something that specific

Comment: Oh... Thanks for the response. In case anyone finds a solution please tell...

Comment: If it's not possible could I do something so that people could upload in the media section in my wordpress account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to this on free Wordpress.com is embedding a Jotform form - that form allows uploading an attachment.

https://wordpress.com/support/forms/jotform/

It won’t automatically upload to the media library. But if you enable the Post by Email feature on your site and use the PBE email address for your Jotform notification email, that can then automatically create a new post on your site from the form submission.

I’m not sure to what extent you’ll be able to customize the Jotform email with the PBE parameters to control the created post’s formatting and settings, but it’s an option you can look into.

https://wordpress.com/support/post-by-email/